# htaccess redirect based on wordpress cookie value

Tags: apache

I am trying to redirect users without a cookie "wordpress_logged_in" from the "wp-json/" to the base url of the website. Unfortunately when I go to the url "wp-json" nothing changes and the JSON shows as normal. When I test the script to a directory that exist on the server (folder called "test") the script works fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-json/wp/v2/(users|comments|posts|pages|media|types|statuses|taxonomies|categories|tags|settings) [NC] 
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

## I've tried

Incognito mode, clearing cookies/history/cache, different browsers, different web servers, I've tried creating the wp-json folder but that breaks the API

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Always good to know what's not working. Any reason to not include the carret in the cookie regex  `!^.*wordpress...` ?

Comment: Also better change `http://` to `https://` in the last rule, as it will end up in an additional rewrite which can also be an issue.

Comment: @SamSegers that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Everything gets redirected to wp-json instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Quickly tested the following with 2 pages index.php -> test.php: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)index.php
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1test.php [L,QSA]` and this works. I suggest you to simplify your test to figure out the rootcause.

Comment: The redirection works with files and folders but not with JSON. So when I go to www.websitename/wp-json/ all the REST API information is displayed and it won't redirect. Just to say wp-json is not a folder, it's a rest api endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the "wordpress_logged_in" was changing due to a plugin that was installed. I think that solves the misery.